# GKScore challengeComposeControllerWithPlayers not showing view

Tags: ios7, game-center

Here's my code:

```
GKScore *scoreObj = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
scoreObj.value = playerScore;

[scoreObj 
    challengeComposeControllerWithPlayers:playerIDs 
                                  message:msg
                        completionHandler:^(UIViewController *composeController,
                                            BOOL didIssueChallenge, 
                                            NSArray *sentPlayerIDs) {
                // I don't really care what you do
            }];
```

When I run the code, I get no overlay at all, and no error messages in the log.

Currently, `playerIDs` is an NSMutableArray that's empty. I don't know if that's related, but I don't want to have to pre-populate a list - that's what this native UI is suppoed to do for me, right? `mgs` is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in iOS 7 `initWithCategory:` is deprecated. Use `initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:` instead. As the documentation says:

> Provides a challenge compose view controller with pre-selected player identifiers and a preformatted, player-editable message.

So save a pointer to this view controller, present it from your current view controller and dismiss it from within the completion handler.

Assuming you're within the implementation of your current viewController do the following:

```
GKScore *scoreObj = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:category] autorelease];
scoreObj.value = playerScore;

UIViewController *vc = [scoreObj  challengeComposeControllerWithPlayers:playerIDs 
                                  message:msg
                        completionHandler:^(UIViewController *composeController,
                                            BOOL didIssueChallenge, 
                                            NSArray *sentPlayerIDs) {
   [composeController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
                // I don't really care what you do
            }];
[self presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
```

This should displayed the viewController as intended.